# Jquery Dialogbox in webforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I used this [Plugin in Webforms](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated). I have Content Place holder on my Form so I converted the Code into Below:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('#<%=dialog.ClientID %>').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
        $('#<%=opener.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        $('#<%=dialog.ClientID %>').dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<div id="dialog" runat="server" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<button runat="server" id="opener">Open Dialog</button>


</asp:Content>
```

But it is not working. How do i solve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect to happen, and what's actually happening?

Comment: i see nothing on my screen when i click the button just flicking something at div.I'm expecting Dialogbox .I have posted the URL on my Question please look  that

Comment: I'm not familiar with asp, hence asking - are the ` $('#<%=dialog.ClientID %>')` things working..? Can you add an alert or something in the buttons click event and check whether it is working..? Do you have any errors in console..?

Comment: @T J - alert working ,i have no errors but getting some Warnings.

Comment: Make sure that the button isn't posting back to the server. Try using a regular button and not making it a server control to help avoid postback. You can also try making it a regular <a> and using styling to make it appear as a button.

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` element submits the page back to the server after being clicked. This is its default behavior inside a form (a Webforms page is a form) and that's why you cannot see the dialog.

You can just add a `type="button"` to your button like this:

```
<button runat="server" type="button" id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

It will prevent the button from posting the page back to the server and you will be able to see the dialog.